# How to test DAO methods using Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, dao

I've started to discovered Mockito library and there is a question for which I didn't find the proper answer.

If I have for example such method in my UserDAO class that saves user in database:

```
public class UserDAO{
...
 public void create(User user) {
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ResultSet generatedKeys = null;
        try {

            connection = getConnection();
            pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_USER,
                    PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            int counter = 1;
            pstmt.setString(counter++, user.getFirstName());
            pstmt.setString(counter++, user.getLastName());
            pstmt.setString(counter++, user.getEmail());
            pstmt.setString(counter++, user.getPassword());
            pstmt.setString(counter++, user.getRole());
            pstmt.setString(counter, user.getLang());

            pstmt.execute();
            connection.commit();
            generatedKeys = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();

            if (generatedKeys.next()) {
                user.setId(generatedKeys.getInt(Fields.GENERATED_KEY));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            rollback(connection);
            LOG.error("Can not create a user", e);
        } finally {
            close(connection);
            close(pstmt);
            close(generatedKeys);
        }
    }
  ....
}
```

How should I test it ?

If I want to test for example a DAO class then I need to create a `DataSource` mock, `Connection` mock, `ResultSet` mock etc ? And so not to test the database itself ?

But what if I want to also test the behavior of dao and database ?

Would you please produce some code samples, links that could be helpful and show best approaches of doing it ?

Comment: A proper DAO should not manage transactions, ie, no commits or rollbacks. Normally, transaction demarcation is done at a higher layer, and usually (Java EE, Spring, etc.) it's applied implicitly.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here is a good start using Mockito to test your UserDAO.  This code uses a good amount of the Mockito features, so you can see how to use them.  Let me know if you have questions.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyInt;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doNothing;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestUserDAO {

    @Mock
    DataSource mockDataSource;
    @Mock
    Connection mockConn;
    @Mock
    PreparedStatement mockPreparedStmnt;
    @Mock
    ResultSet mockResultSet;
    int userId = 100;

    public TestUserDAO() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws SQLException {
        when(mockDataSource.getConnection()).thenReturn(mockConn);
        when(mockDataSource.getConnection(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(mockConn);
        doNothing().when(mockConn).commit();
        when(mockConn.prepareStatement(anyString(), anyInt())).thenReturn(mockPreparedStmnt);
        doNothing().when(mockPreparedStmnt).setString(anyInt(), anyString());
        when(mockPreparedStmnt.execute()).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE);
        when(mockPreparedStmnt.getGeneratedKeys()).thenReturn(mockResultSet);
        when(mockResultSet.next()).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FALSE);
        when(mockResultSet.getInt(Fields.GENERATED_KEYS)).thenReturn(userId);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateWithNoExceptions() throws SQLException {

        UserDAO instance = new UserDAO(mockDataSource);
        instance.create(new User());

        //verify and assert
        verify(mockConn, times(1)).prepareStatement(anyString(), anyInt());
        verify(mockPreparedStmnt, times(6)).setString(anyInt(), anyString());
        verify(mockPreparedStmnt, times(1)).execute();
        verify(mockConn, times(1)).commit();
        verify(mockResultSet, times(2)).next();
        verify(mockResultSet, times(1)).getInt(Fields.GENERATED_KEYS);
    }

    @Test(expected = SQLException.class)
    public void testCreateWithPreparedStmntException() throws SQLException {

         //mock
         when(mockConn.prepareStatement(anyString(), anyInt())).thenThrow(new SQLException());


        try {
            UserDAO instance = new UserDAO(mockDataSource);
            instance.create(new User());
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            //verify and assert
            verify(mockConn, times(1)).prepareStatement(anyString(), anyInt());
            verify(mockPreparedStmnt, times(0)).setString(anyInt(), anyString());
            verify(mockPreparedStmnt, times(0)).execute();
            verify(mockConn, times(0)).commit();
            verify(mockResultSet, times(0)).next();
            verify(mockResultSet, times(0)).getInt(Fields.GENERATED_KEYS);
            throw se;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this code - it compiles but at run-time the InvalidUseOfMatchersException is thrown from both methods

Comment: You have to show which line is throwing that.  When matchers r used as input to a method then all the input must be matchers.

Comment: It is thrown from the line: `when(mockConn.prepareStatement(anyString(),  PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)).thenReturn(mockPreparedStmnt);`

Comment: use anyInt instead of Preparedstatement.return_generated_keys.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: There is another occurrence of the same.  Just watch out for them.  And fix them.

Comment: I'm typing on an iPad here and it sucks.  Ok I fixed all three of them.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed them all. Also the test with sql exception failures, I think it's because I have catch in my create method.

Comment: And to sum up: could you tell what we're testing with such tests ? - that proper methods called in proper amount of times ? is that all I should test about dao when testing it by itself ?

Comment: SP when test passed and the other failed?  Remember these are examples.  You will have to alter it to fit your exact need.

Comment: Terrible use of mocking, in my opinion, as the test is complicated and tightly coupled to implementation details of the DAO class. It would be much better to only have integration tests using an actual database; the tests would be shorter and simpler, and even better, they would not need modification if the DAO is rewritten to use JPA (though in that case the DAO wouldn't even need to exist in the first place).

Comment: @Rogério what you suggest is terrible.  First, you are not verifying that your correct methods are being called.  THis is important part of unit testing.  Second you are suggesting having your unit tests connect to an external database, unit tests are suppose to not connect to anything external.  Third, integration testing is a separate testing stage, it not unit testing.  Also, I think when you write code with unit test in mind, then your unit tests will look cleaner.

Comment: @Rogério also, the question specifically asks about Mockito.  Your comment is suggesting to not use Mockito and hence does not belong in my answer.

Comment: @Rogério please left an answer so I can see how it should look like from your perspective

Comment: @JoseMartinez Ask any creator of a mocking library and they will tell you that mocking the JDBC API is a bad idea; normally, they recommend mocking the DAO (when testing a higher layer), but *not* its internal dependencies. Regarding unit testing x integration testing, I don't think there is general consensus that you should always favor unit testing, or write both kinds of tests for the same code. Personally, I prefer integration testing; mocking is way too often abused and misused, in my experience.

Comment: @JoseMartinez To me, the question is really "How should I test it ?". Use of Mockito, or any other mocking tool, is just not a good idea for testing DAOs. This isn't just my opinion; search around and you will find plenty of experienced people saying the same, DAOs should be tested against an actual database.

Comment: @Rogério, dao is code.  Unit test is to test every branch and line of code.  Then use tools to verify code coverage.  This is true for all code.  Dao is no exception.  If you want to setup an external DB during your unit testing and then hit 100% code coverage by using your dao's against that external DB, then that's fine.  As long as you hit your code coverage goals.  I never access external systems during unit testing though.  You will make your unit tests more complicated.  Also, as mentioned you need mock objects to verify that your code arrived at the right answer correctly.

Comment: @Rogério another thing to consider is that unit testing is executed when ever I build. This ensures we catch any issues right away. If during your unit testing you are waiting for connections to be established then your unit test cycle will be a lot longer then if you used no external sources.  I was able to remove external sources from unit test in a new team I worked for and made the coding a lot faster.  What took minutes now took a few seconds.  Also, there were less issues with "can't test, external system is down".

Comment: @JoseMartinez Actually, I *do* hit 100% code coverage (well, currently about 99% :^) with my integration tests that hit an external database. Why should I still create unit tests, then? It would increase the effort for no visible gain. From experience, integration tests are easier to write than unit tests with mocking, and they still run quite fast. I don't know why you think that you "need" mocking to properly test application code; I certainly don't need, except in few situations where I *do* use mocking (for example, to mock the JSF `FacesContext`) while still having an integration test.

Comment: @Rogério, http://www.lenholgate.com/blog/2005/10/unit-testing-and-accessing-external-systems.html.  If you design your code with testing in mind you end up with cleaner code and cleaner test.  I think if the OP had been doing unit testing for a while then the code would look different and the unit tests shorter.

Comment: Good integration tests will only take seconds, even when hitting an external RDBMS such as PostgreSQL or Oracle. Currently, I have a suite with about 150 such tests, and they take less than 10 seconds. A Jenkins build machine runs them all on every commit. Most of the time, though, I only run the relevant tests (a much smaller number) from the Java IDE, before commiting the changes.

Comment: @Rogério Yeah right.  That sounds like the "no true scots man fallacy".  Here is another article on the topic.  http://jasonpolites.github.io/tao-of-testing/ch4-1.1.html

Comment: @JoseMartinez Please, do read the article you referenced; it does not say what you thinks it says. Instead, it says "wrap access to these systems up in a single place and provide an interface that the rest of the code can use to interact with the system". That is, they recommend either using a higher-level API than JDBC (such as ORM/JPA, which generates all SQL code) that can be more easily mocked, or to only mock the DAOs themselves, not their internal dependencies (ie, the JDBC API here). That JDBC code you propose to mock *is* the "ugly stuff" they recommend to be isolated.

Comment: @JoseMartinez I *do* design my code with testing in mind; that's why I never use JDBC directly, prefering either JPA or some easier to use JDBC wrapper library. Also, I avoid DAOs in general, as they are not needed when you have good application architecture and design.

Comment: @Rogério. We both are in agreement on that point.  I am not trying to redesign his code.  I am trying to answer the question...here is the code, now test it.  Can you provide an answer that took literally 3 minutes to type out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70519/discussion-between-jose-martinez-and-rogerio).

Answer (score 7):

> But what if I want to also test the behavior of dao and database ?

If you indeed want to test the database (as you should!), there's no way around it - you need an actual database. Mockito, albeit being a great library, is probably the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: ok, thats cleared something. but about the case when I want to test just the dao itself ?

Comment: That's integration testing.  Not the same as unit testing.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you *should* test it:

```
public class UserDAOTest extends IntegrationTests
{
    // Or do it in a @Before method, if needed.
    UserDAO dao = new UserDAO();

    @Test
    public void createValidUser() {
        User validUser = new User(
            "John", "Smith", "johns@gmail.com", "Abc123!@",
            "admin", "en"); // or use setters as needed

        dao.create(validUser);

        assertEntityCreatedInDB(validUser);
    }

    @Test
    public void attemptToCreateInvalidUser() {
        User invalidUser = new User("", null, null, "", null, "XY");

        dao.create(invalidUser);

        // This really shouldn't be done this way, as DAOs are not supposed
        // to manage transactions; instead, a suitable, descriptive
        // exception should be thrown by the DAO and checked in the test.
        assertTransactionWasRolledBack();
    }
}
```

A couple notes about the above:

1) The tests look short, simple, and easy to understand, as *they should be*; if they look big and ugly as those in another answer, you are doing something fundamentally wrong.

2) Test code can and should have its own infrastructure helpers, such as the `IntegrationTests` base class, which will hide any nasty JDBC/ORM access from the actual tests. I implemented such helpers in several projects, so I know this can be done, but that would be stuff for other questions.

Comment: assertTransactionWasRolledBack isn´t resolved by IntelliJ. Are these methods resolved by a library or implemented manually. If so, could you share the implementation? Thanks

Comment: As I mentioned in note "2" above, the `IntegrationTests` base test class has such infrastructure methods as `assertEntityCreatedInDB(anEntity)` and `assertTransactionWasRolledBack()`. This [sample code](https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/tree/master/samples/petclinic) has similar test infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

A tool like [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/howto.html) combined with JUnit could help you testing your DAOs with the database. DBUnit helps you inserting test data to the database before your UnitTest and compare the data in the database with your expectation after the test.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example from my quiz application

```
    @Test
fun quizDao() {
    val database = mockk<AppDatabase>()
    val dao = mockk<QuizDao>()
    val application = mockk<Application>()
    val appModule = mockk<AppModule>()
//quiz
    val quiz1 = Quiz("Joe","Best Quize","people Around the World","General",23)
//Questions
    val questions1 : Questions = Questions(1,"What's your group", "G1","G2","G3","G4","G1")


    every { dao.getQuizQuestions(23) } returns listOf(questions1)

    assertEquals(listOf(questions1),dao.getQuizQuestions(23))

}
```

}