# Should I synchronize getConnection() of DataSource

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, connection-pooling

I have this singelton with Connection Pool.

```
public enum ConnectionPool {
    INSTANCE;

    private DataSource ds = null;

    ConnectionPool() {
      try {
         final Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
         ds = (DataSource) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/test");
      } catch (NamingException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

   public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
      return ds.getConnection();
   }
}
```

Should I synchronize getConnection() in order to prevent getting the same instance from different threads? It looks like it has been already synchronized by Tomcat but I'm not sure(I use Tomcat 8).

Comment: You should use Singleton pattern for this.

Comment: @RaghuKNair, this is a singleton.

Comment: Singleton is never the right pattern. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons

Comment: I've never synchronized it in my life.

Comment: @Samuel Nevertheless anything bound into a namespace is a singleton by definition.

Comment: @Samuel oh.. sorry I did see the enum . You dont have to synchronize  here

Comment: @RaghuKNair Singleton does not imply thread-safety.

Comment: Just wondering if there is an exception in creating ConnectionPool you may get a NPE as ds is null

Comment: See [is javax.sql.DataSource thread safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872685/is-javax-sql-datasource-thread-safe).

Comment: @RaghuKNair  yes, I'll fix it. Thanks :)

Comment: @Samuel  I agree with you in strict terms but that is common pattern used  in lazy loading.  enum are better than singleton pattern but cannot be used in all situations.  Singlton with double null check and volatile instance seems to be decent implementation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though it is not explicitly mentioned in java docs, `DataSource#getConnection` method is designed to be called concurrently on a single DataSource instance.

You do not need to provide client-level synchronization in general case.

Restriction in java docs is probably omitted to provide flexibility for implementations.

Comment: ["that said"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/that_said) generally introduces a counterpoint to your previous statement.

Comment: @shmosel thank you, I thought it has a different meaning

Answer (score 1):

Well, you shouldn't have this "ConnectionPool" in the first place. Consider using a tested one that actually does connection pooling.

Anyways, the thread-safety of your class is that of `DataSource` because you delegating to it and it is the only shared state you have. There is nothing in the JDBC API that ensures thread-safety and hence you need to check the implementation details.

Comment: I must use DOA classes so invoke lookup() in each one doesn't seem right

Comment: Well, you can use a library, inject a datasource instead if the singelton anti-pattern

Comment: Thanks for tip I didn't know about recourse injection.